# SQL Get associated data from a third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how to get a result that show me all the orders, all invoices associated to every order and all payments associated to every invoice. I got the orders and their related invoices but only get the first payment, not every payment associated to one invoice. Any advice?

```
SELECT orders.n_o, invoices.n_in, payments.n_pay 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN invoices ON order.n_o = invoices.n_o_fk 
LEFT JOIN payments ON invoices.n_in = payments.n_pay_fk 
GROUP BY invoices.n_in;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: why do you group?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you don't want the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.n_o, i.n_in, p.n_pay
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     invoices i
     ON o.n_o = i.n_o_fk LEFT JOIN
     payments p
     ON i.n_in = p.n_pay_fk ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. Exactly what I wanted.